# How to check connection between my PC and some IP address?

Tags: networking, internet, ip

I'm trying to check connection to specific IP automatically.

If there is a connection established then take some action, if there is no connecton take another action.

Comment: you can use `netstat` command to check your connection status with foreign IP address and make a bash script for whatever actions you would like to perform

Comment: Read `man ping`